# Is there a clever way of avoiding nested events in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-events

I have a Shape which I want to scale in the following way:

1. The user moves the mouse over the shape
2. They click the Control key
3. They use the mouse scroll to scale up and down accordingly.

This is how I solved this: (I am not including the implementations of my method as the sole idea, not the actual implementation, is the subject of this question):

```
public void addScaling(Shape shape)
{
    shape.setOnMouseEntered(e ->
    {
        (shape.getScene()).setOnKeyPressed(e2 ->
            shape.setOnScroll(e3 -> scalingMethod())
    }

    shape.setOnMouseExited(e -> 
    {
        (shape.getScene()).setOnKeyPressed(null);
        shape.setOnScroll(null);
    }
}
```

However, I am not satisfied with this piece of code - it looks terrible. 
Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, a scroll event won't be fired on a node unless the mouse is over it anyway. So all you need is

```
shape.setOnScroll(e -> {
    if (e.isControlDown()) {
        scalingMethod();
    }
});
```

If you really need to check if the mouse is over the shape, do

```
shape.setOnScroll(e -> {
    if (e.isControlDown() && shape.isHover()) {
        scalingMethod();
    }
});
```